# Why this in anonymous inner class represent different object that in lambda

Tags: java, lambda, anonymous-inner-class

as [read](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_lambda_expressions.htm)

> Lambda expression eliminates the need of anonymous class and gives a
>   very simple yet powerful functional programming capability to Java.

what I understand that lambda is replacement of inner classes with single method to eliminates the bulkiness of the code

```
public class Main {

    interface Foo {
        int x = 20;
        void bar();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main app = new Main();
        app.start();
    }

    int x = 10;

    public void start()
    {
        Main test = new Main();
        test.test(new Foo()
        {
            @Override
            public void bar() {
                System.out.println("Inner Class X= " + this.x);
            }
        });

        test.test(() -> System.out.println("Lambda X= " + this.x));
    }

    public void test(Foo foo) {
        foo.bar();
    }

}
```

the output I get is

```
Inner Class X = 20
Lambda X = 10
```

what I expect is

```
Inner Class X = 20
Lambda X = 20
```

Comment: `this` refers to different things in a lambda Vs an anonymous class. Why? Because that's how the two are defined in the language spec.

Comment: both times you called this, it was in the scope of a different class.

Comment: Aside from anything else, `x` is static on `Foo`, so don't try to refer to it through an instance.

Comment: Relevant language spec [quote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3): "The value denoted by this in a lambda body is the same as the value denoted by this in the surrounding context."

Answer (score -1):

Consider that a lambda is not an object.

We your first implementation, you make an object of the inner class by doing `new Foo()`. So in this implementation `this` refers to this object.

In the lambda implementation, there is not such an object an `this` refers to the enclosing class.